# Install pyyaml without libyaml

Tags: python, pyyaml

How can I pyyaml via pip without the libyaml dependency? How can I add that to my requirements.txt file

The documentation for PyYaml states that I can call setup.py like this `'python setup.py --without-libyaml install'`, but running `pip install pyyaml --install-option='--without-libyaml'` errors with `error: option --without-libyaml not recognized`.

Comment: The PyYAML documentation only [has a case for opting _in_ to libyaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation). You can simply do `pip install pyyaml` to install it without libyaml support.

Comment: Their github repo has the `--without-libyaml` flag https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml That's why I mentioned it. Also, on my machine (MacOS X 10.11) it installs with libyaml by default.

Answer (score 1):

To install without libyaml you need to use the `--global-option` parameter, not `--install-option`.

You have to run pip like this:

```
pip install pyyaml --global-option=--without-libyaml
```